# Visual Studio 2013 not finding include path

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to link the opencv library to a project, but I keep getting the error

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I have a path variable called OPENCV_DIR that I've confirm paths to the correct folder using cygwin. I've also confirmed that the file `core.hpp`exists in my include directory in a folder called `opencv2`.

I created two property sheets for Visual Studios, one for debugging one for release, and both have the identical instructions as follows:

```
c++>general>additional include directories: $(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include

Linker>general>additional library directories: $(OPENCV_DIR)\lib

Linker>input>additional dependencies: 
IlmImfd.lib
libjasperd.lib
libpngd.lib
libjpegd.lib
libtiffd.lib
libwebpd.lib
opencv_calib3d300d.lib
opencv_core300d.lib
opencv_features2d300d.lib
opencv_flann300d.lib
opencv_hal300d.lib
opencv_highgui300d.lib
opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib
opencv_imgproc300d.lib
opencv_ml300d.lib
opencv_objdetect300d.lib
opencv_photo300d.lib
opencv_shape300d.lib
opencv_stitching300d.lib
opencv_superres300d.lib
opencv_ts300d.lib
opencv_video300d.lib
opencv_videoio300d.lib
opencv_videostab300d.lib
zlibd.lib
ippicvmt.lib
comctl32.lib
vfw32.lib
```

I have confirmed in cygwin that `$OPENCV_DIR/../../include` and `$OPENCV_DIR/lib` lead to the correct directories, although it doesn't accept the syntax `$(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include` or `$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib`, oddly enough.

I've tried not using the path variable `OPENCV_DIR` and giving Visual Studios the full file-path. I've also tried using the cygwin syntax instead of the parenthetical and backslash syntax, again to no avail.

Reading through threads of people who had a similar issue, there was discussion over using a 64bit version of opencv with a 32bit compiler causing issues. I'm building a win32 application, but I was only able to find a x64 version of opencv? Is this the issue?

Can anyone tell me why Visual Studios can't find this file in a directory that is given in a property sheet?

Comment: You can use the same header for debug and release version but the library should be different. You can't use debug version of library in release version and vice versa. For x64 app, you should link to x64 libraries. Make sure your include directories for both Debug and Release versions include the path that OpenCV folder

Comment: I have changed the linker input to no longer direct to debugger libraries for the release (in this case removed the 'd' before the '.lib'). This doesn't seem to have broken anything further, but the original problem remains. How do I check if I'm building a x64 or a x32 app? I know the libraries are x64. I am building a Win32 windows app, is that indicative of building x32? (Sorry, I'm a little new at this)

Comment: Do you use more props in your project? You should set something like: $(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories) or VS will use only top-most props only.